# Maven plugin conditional execution based on a previous plugin's execution (maven-compiler-plugin)

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to conditionally execute a goal in compile phase, based on whether the maven-compiler-plugin actually detected source changes and therefore compiled and produced new class files?

My use case would be to do things like run findbugs or jacoco plugins only when there's new byte code in the project.

Currently, I unconditionally run findbugs by hooking it into the compile phase:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>findbugs-check-compile</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

However, if I repeatedly execute "mvn package" I get:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ my-prj ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] >>> findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.1:check (findbugs-check-compile) > :findbugs @ my-prj >>>
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.1:findbugs (findbugs) @ my-prj ---
[INFO] Fork Value is true
[INFO] Done FindBugs Analysis....
```

Notice how maven-compiler-plugin detects "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date". I'd like to only execute findbugs:check afterwards if this is NOT the case (or equivalently, I'd like to SKIP the "findbugs:check" goal execution if this indeed IS the case and nothing has changed).

NOTE 1: I know about profiles and conditional activation based on things like OS / architecture / system properties / etc, but my understanding is that these are evaluated early when maven starts, and cannot change later during the build.

NOTE 2: I've also seen maven-ant-plugin mentioned, but I'd like to just skip the extra plugin's execution altogether. I don't want to add an antrun execution just to be able to skip findbugs.

NOTE 3: I need to be able to do this for multiple plugins, not just findbugs

Comment: I agree with @javapopo. The real question is: why would you want to introduce that much complexity into your build? One of the key things with Maven is that two people can look at a POM and quickly figure out what's going on. Introducing intricate conditionals is just going to complicate things when it doesn't work. You have Maven's build life-cycle and you have your plugins. Keep it simple. If your build is taking too long, perhaps splitting it up could be an alternative. At work, our Jenkins server only generates FB/PMD reports once every night, but a quick CI build with every commit.

Comment: I understand the idea behind the POM. I don't think we're talking about something overly complex though: the case of "something changed" is quite central to the build. One would hope it was supported somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be honest I dont think there is a way to do this. Only the sort of workarounds but not exactly your exact need (based on profiles, property setting from profile1 to be picked up by another profile etc).

Something close to that is usually achieved with tools like jenkins, where you set a basic job e.g do a package (compile) if it succeeds or completes or you see something being generated, then you activate a post-build job to execute find bugs.

Comment: I am accepting this as the correct answer since it really does look to be impossible.